# Overlaying boxplot with histogram in R

Tags: r

I have the following code,

```
d <- mtcars

library(plotly)
# box on top / hist bottom
boxplot<-plot_ly(d, x = ~mpg, type = "box", name = "mpg")
histogram<-plot_ly(d, x = ~mpg, type = "histogram", name = "mpg")
```

and I want to put the boxplot on the top of the histogram with same scale like in the picture below:

[image]

I tried with the subplot() R function but I didn't get the required result

```
subplot(boxplot,histogram) %>%   layout(showlegend=FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `shareX` argument to share the same X-axis and the `nrows` argument to place it vertically :

```
subplot(boxplot,histogram,nrows=2,shareX=TRUE) %>%   layout(showlegend=FALSE)
```

You can also eliminate the lines if you set :

```
ax <- list(
  showgrid = FALSE
)
boxplot<-plot_ly(d, x = ~mpg, type = "box", name = "mpg")%>%  
  layout(showlegend=FALSE,xaxis = ax,yaxis = ax)
histogram<-plot_ly(d, x = ~mpg, type = "histogram", name = "mpg")%>%  
  layout(showlegend=FALSE,xaxis = ax,yaxis = ax)

subplot(boxplot,histogram,nrows=2,shareX=TRUE)
```

[image]